# Xcode 13 - USDZ available animation didn't work

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, augmented-reality, realitykit

After I update the **Xcode to 13** the **animation** that comes with the **USDZ** is not played anymore in the **Reality Composer** / **RealityKit** even though it's working fine on **older Xcode 12 and 11**

the problem: **'Nothing happen when play any USDZ anitmation even when run it on real device'**

Any one face this problem cause didn't find a solution and update to fix it yet

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12033358/ahmad-mustafa A year on almost; did you hear about any progress on this?

Comment: Yes the problem is solved you have to update all the USDZ with the new Xcode 13 and later and the problem will be solved 100%